# email to a group defined in gmail from unix

Tags: shell, email, unix, ksh

I have a group defined in gmail (TestGroup) which has a list of users. How can I email to the list of users by referring just the group name from shell script (ksh)? I'm wondering how the script would know which mail server to look for the definition of group. I've tried following which don't work which is pretty obvious.

```
echo "test body" | mailx -s "test subject" TestGroup@gmail.com
echo "test body" | mailx -s "test subject" TestGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get the group without authenticating with gmail which may be tough with just shell. Use one of the Google Data client libraries (best for you is probably Python) to connect to the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?csw=1#retrieving_a_single_contact_group). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556375/my-contacts-group-google-contacts) provides a great start.

Once you have the contact group you can send an email by following [these instructions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Email) or use an open source library like [this one](https://github.com/charlierguo/gmail).

Answer (score 0):

You can make your unix user's email address a member of Google group and then you can use

```
echo "test body" | mailx -s "test subject" TestGroup@gmail.com
```

command to send emails to Google group.

Comment: Did as you said but the mail is not sent. Is there anything else that I need to check? 
PS: Just to make clear TestGroup is the name of group and not TestGroup@gmail.com

Comment: Group name is usually something like `group123@googlegroup.com` on Google group. Aren't you using same here?

Comment: I created a group following this link http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Mailing-List-in-Gmail . It's a few step process. I'm not sure what the email id of the group would be.

Comment: ok this is different from Google group as only your gmail account knows this group name. I don't think from outside you can access this group. You can use the alternate approach as I suggested by setting a **new private Google Group**

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread.  However, I would use the following code:

```
for I in `cat TestGroup`;
   do echo "test body" | mailx -s "test subject" $I ;
done
```

Hope that helps.